# Control flow analysis for Tuple Union Types

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, tuples

Is there a way to tell typescript that a union type of tuples satisifies the type constraints for any code path in the following example without manually specifying each case in the function body?

```
type options = 
    [string, (a:string) => number]
    | [number, (b:number) => string ]

function f( [input,fn]: options) {
    // Error: Cannot invoke an expression which lacks a call signature
    return fn(input)
}
```

If `input` is a `string` then `fn` will accept a `string`, and if `input` is a `number`, `fn` will accept a `number`.  And yet, Typescript believes `fn` is unable to accept the input because it believes it is `string | number`.

The possible functions are either `(string) => number | (number) => string` where as the input is `string | number`.  If the functions accepted `(string|number) => number | (string|number) => string` typescript would be fine with it.  But I want to tell Typescript that there is no possible way `fn` can't accept `arg` (which is true).

I understand why Typescript is determining the individual types are incompatible.  But I am looking for a way to tell typescript that each possible tuple is self contained and can invoke its own arg with its own function.

Comment: Seems like correct behavior to me? `f` accepts a tuple and you are trying to give it a string or a number?

Comment: Do you mean to make a recursive call, should `f(input) `be `fn(input)`?

Comment: I think he does yeah, due to that last paragraph mentioning `fn` instead of `f`. It's not a typo in the question, since the error he gets is the one you would get for calling `f`. I amended my answer to reflect this intent. Fixing that bug would still fail though, due to some rather complex type theory. I wonder if this is a toy example, or something that you actually want to use?

Comment: This is something I want to use to type the possible accepted arguments for calling a REST endpoint. @SimonMeskens

Answer (score 2):

Here's a typesafe way to make it work. The `as` keyword is not a cast, it *would* complain if the types weren't compatible.

```
type options = 
    [string, (a:string) => number]
    | [number, (b:number) => string ]

function f( [input,fn]: options) {
   return (fn as (a: string | number) => string | number)(input);
}
```

TypeScript isn't smart enough to figure this one out by itself, so it needs a little help by widening the type just a little bit.

Comment: Yes, because that's a completely different example that does work. Note that in the original question, he is calling recursively, not calling the callback.

Comment: Maybe it's an error on his part, I'll amend my answer

Comment: Rewrote the answer to fit the question

Comment: I'd really like to avoid enumerating all possible types in the function body.

I suppose even casting `fn as any` is typesafe because it will be guarded at the invocation level.  That way you avoid the enumeration in the function body.

Comment: It wouldn't be typesafe completely, but yeah, the call point would be properly typesafe.